# Sql : left join exclude values based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out this without any success i have tried going through several posts but cannot come to a solution. Situation is like this : ( There are no foreign key constraints )
`Table A   ID | VAL     Table B ID|VAL|TEMP       RESULT REQUIRED

           1 | A                1| A | 2           A
           1 | B                1| A | 2           C
           1 | C                1| B | 1           D
           1 | D                1| C | 2           E
           1 | E                1| D | 2           F
           1 | F                1| G | 6           H
           1 | H`


When i run
 `SELECT DISTINCT A.VAL,B.TEMP FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.VAL=B.VAL AND B.TEMP > 1`
 This is returning all rows of TABLE A and rows which are common to TABLE B but not validating the condition ( b.val > 1) because since row B is in Table A, it is getting included in the result . However i want that if val b < 2 then it should be not included in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select distinct a.val
from a
left outer join b on (a.val = b.val)
where 
  (b.temp > 1 or b.val is null)
```

You want to do the test on B.TEMP after doing the outer join. In the where clause, you are testing for two things. Firstly, you a checking that the value of TEMP is greater than 1. This is the condition set forward in the question. The second condition (`b.val is null`) covers those rows from table A that don't have a corresponding row in table B. For example, rows 'E', 'F' and 'G' in table A don't match to anything in table B, so all the columns of B will be null after the outer join. you might want to look at this link for more information on outer joins: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Howveer, I have noticed that the rows in table B don't need to be unique. You have two rows where VAL= 'A'. What would happen if the TEMP column had different values where one met the condition and the other didn't.

Another option for getting the result might just be to use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`. An example might be:

```
select * from a
where a.val not in (
  select val 
  from b 
  where temp < 2
);
```

Comment: So what is concept of b.val is null. By the way thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: @JasSra I've added a little more information to the answer which hopefully will help with understanding the (b.val is null)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude results from the second table, then don't use a `left outer join`.  Just use an `inner join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.VAL, B.TEMP
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B 
     ON A.VAL = B.VAL AND B.TEMP > 1;
```

Or, in your case, you might want `B.TEMP < 2`.

Comment: I tried this already however B.Temp > 1 seems to be of no effect because it is still including value. However as suggested above if i check for b.null then result omits that row.  Thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Add following WHERE clause to your query

```
WHERE B.Val IS NOT NULL
```